# MFC - Missing Icons next to Right-Click Popup Menu

Tags: c++, mfc

This is using Microsoft Foundation Classes with Visual Studio 2017

I have a Popup menu that appears when I right-click on a tree item and it has 2 entries "Delete Node" and "Properties". To the left of "Delete Node" is a red X icon (signifying delete) and an icon of a hand holding a sheet of paper (signifying "Properties"). All well and good.

But a 2nd Popup menu appears for a different type of tree item. It also has a "Delete Node" and "Properties". But *no icons appears to the left of these entries!!!*. There is a left vertical strip (which is where the icons would be placed) for the missing icons.

How do I get those same icons next to the 2nd Popup menu?
I have looked at the code and the Popup menus using the Resource editor, visually, and in text and don't see how this is specified.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer. It is using the Icon from a corresponding toolbar.
Because the menu ID handler is missing from the toolbar, no icon is displayed.

The icon on the popup menu is "borrowed" from the toolbar if the same menu ID is in use.

This is a hypothesis but I am reasonably sure that it is true.